# React route to subdomain from 2nd level domain

Tags: javascript, reactjs, subdomain, multi-tenant

There is a login page on my React site which has this url (locally)

http://localhost:3000/login

When the user logs in, the server returns a bunch of information about the user including a list of companies, each of which has a subdomain element.  All of this data gets put into localStorage upon logging in.

My goal here is that when a user logs into the site, they will get immediately redirected to the home page but with a subdomain matching the first company in their list of companies returned from the server.

This is what have so far:

1. This file is a global utility file which I will import into the login page:

```
const getSubdomainHref = function() {
    const storedUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user") || '{}')
    let newHref = window.location.origin

    if (storedUser.companies.length > 0) {
        newHref = window.location.protocol + '//' + storedUser.companies[0].subdomain + '.' + window.location.host
    } 

    return newHref
}

export { getSubdomainHref };
```

2. And this is part of my login page (the important part)

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { getSubdomainHref } from "./../utils";

//other code

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user.user_type !== 'anonymous') {
      let newHref = getSubdomainHref()
      navigate(newHref + "/");
    }
  }, [user, navigate]);
```

This is not working, What happens when I log in is this.

Initial page:

http://localhost:3000/login

Resulting page: (note, the subdomain returned is 'cbd')

http://localhost:3000/login/http://cbd.localhost:3000/

how can I make this work?

Note, as I write this, I just had another thought, that being the problem of the localStorage from "localhost" not being readily available at "cbd.localhost".  I'm not sure if this is a problem yet but it might be.

Comment: Hi i was wondering which is the recommended solution using AWS route 54 or window.location?

Comment: in this case, you would need something to reroute on the front end.  that means Javascript and window.location.  Route 53 is for DNS routing only.  and yes technically when you set a new window.location value DNS is involved but this would have been set up already and does not need to change in anyway to support this need

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, so should i create 3 seperate projects (home, admin, shop) and use route 53 to route each (eg. admin.example.com etc..) or 1 react project and reroute according using window.lcoation?

Comment: Depends, if you have three separate React projects hosted on different servers then you might want to set up Rout 53 to redirect DNS to your respective servers. My DNS however has two A records, *.mysite.com and mysite.com both pointing to same IP. I then use NGINX reverse proxy for port level routing. I have not yet discovered any good React components for third level domain routing hence the use of window.location for me.

Comment: Hi Dallas, i currently have 1 project with all 3 sub projects inside (merchant.localhost, admin.localhost and localhost) and im using windows.location to reroute the user to the correct project, but i got told what i should seperate the subprojects into 3 independent projects (which is easy just copy code and paste in new project) then use route 53 to reroute, which do you recoommend?

Comment: Thanks for your confidence in me, but I am in no way an expert on this.  I've never used Route 53.  The only DNS routing I've done is with GoDaddy.  I suspect there are many ways to set up what you want and there are advantages/disadvantages to them.  I can only tell you what I did on my site which is not using R53.  I can see scaling advantages to having separate projects and separate routes (you can use load balancers etc...)  I would trust your friend over me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the `react-router-dom` only handles the internal navigation. It means that it can only navigate or redirect to the URLs within the same react application i.e. `http://localhost:3000`. And that's why the subdomain is interpreted as an internal path and is appended to the current path.

If you need to navigate to an external URL you can use `window.location` object. You can either create a separate component for navigation or just directly use it as shown below :

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { getSubdomainHref } from "./../utils";


  useEffect(() => {
    if (user.user_type !== 'anonymous') {
      let newHref = getSubdomainHref()
      window.location.href = newHref;
    }
  }, [user]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Prince Mittal is 100% correct.  This is what I have chosen to do to solve the problem:

1. on the login page, if you are not already logging in from the correct subdomain what will happen is you will get in the response a 1-time use token which can be used for a short period of time to log in.
2. once the token is received, I will use the window.location.href method to redirect my site to a special page that I will make specifically for this purpose which will take in the token and then immediately pass it to the backend so the user can be re-authenticated.  the url will look something like this:  http://subdomain.localhost:3000/redirect/CODE
3. once the user is logged in they will be redirected to the home page using the normal react navigation method.